# How to succinctly assign a range of one array to a range of another array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

**Background reading**

I'm re-writing some Verilog code in C/C++, and in Verilog you can do something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1) begin
     if (condition(i)) begin
          data_out[index*WIDTH +: WIDTH] = data_in[i*WIDTH +: WIDTH];
          index = index + 1;
     end
end
```

Where at this line:

```
data_out[index*WIDTH +: WIDTH] = data_in[i*WIDTH +: WIDTH];
```

We're saying assign the section of `data_in` starting at position `i*WIDTH` up to `i*WIDTH + WIDTH - 1` to the section of `data_out` starting at position `index*WIDTH` up to `index*WIDTH + WIDTH - 1`.

Similarly, in Python I could do something like this:

```
>>> arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> 
>>> arr1[1:3] = arr2[0:2]
>>> 
>>> print arr1, arr2
['a', 1, 2, 'd'] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I know I can write this in C by using an extra loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1) {
      if (condition(i)) {
           for (k = 0; k < WIDTH; k = k + 1) {
               data_out[index*WIDTH + k] = data_in[i*WIDTH + k];
           }
           index = index + 1;
      }
 }
```

But this is a little tedious when these assignments happen quite often and in nested loops. I'm hoping there's a smarter way.

**Question**

Is there a succinct way to write:

```
arr1[INDEX_A to INDEX_B] = arr2[INDEX_C to INDEX_D];
```

or

```
arr1[STARTING_POSITION_A to SOME_WIDTH] = arr2[STARTING_POSITION_B to SOME_WIDTH];
```

I'm specifically interested in an array of *booleans* if that simplifies the problem.

I can also use C++ for this, but would prefer if the code used simple data types and arrays instead of vectors because it's getting synthesized to hardware and the simpler it is the easier that is.

Comment: The only way to "assign" arrays is to `memcpy` (or loop).

Comment: Do you want it the C (dbushs answer) or C++ (Igors answer) way?

Comment: With Verilog you work with hardware, on programming language you work with CPU and CPU usually do not have instructions to do such bit manipulaton (and it is usually not necessary). Probably is  it not a good idea to move logic from Verilog to C one by one.

Comment: @hellow He got both :)

Comment: Apart from what @Slava said - what could be a purpose of rewriting Verilog code in C (unless it is SystemC) ?

Comment: @Slava That's true but I'm writing this code for [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_synthesis) so the C will be converted to gates, not executed with a CPU.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Obfuscation and timing closure.

Comment: @CharlesClayton Then you probably shouldn't blindly "translate" the code, but rewrite using statements optimized for HLS and use corresponding paradigms..

Comment: Then you explicitly should mention that from the begining, and I hardly doubt that C++ is applicable here

Comment: You should pick a language, `C` or `C++` ? Which one are you actually rewriting in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
std::copy(data_in + i*WIDTH, data_in + (i+1)*WIDTH, data_out + index*WIDTH);
```

or equivalently

```
std::copy(&data_in[i*WIDTH], &data_in[i*WIDTH]+WIDTH, &data_out[index*WIDTH]);
```

Comment: This is the preferred answer for C++. But it is not applicable to C.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `memcpy` to copy multiple array elements:

```
memcpy(&data_out[index*WIDTH], &data_in[i*WIDTH], WIDTH*sizeof(*data_in));
```

The first parameter is the destination memory address, the second is the source address, and the third is the number of bytes to copy.

Note that you need to multiply the number of element by the size of an element in bytes to get the total byte count.

Comment: Note that in C++ this won't work if the type of array elements is not trivially-copyable. In C, of course, everything is trivially copyable.